# The Part Number and Serial Number stamped on the label on the drive - How do I get this from a command prompt?

Tags: hard-drive, command-line

I am getting diagnostics saying my hard drive (an OCZ SSD) is failing. Is there any way from the command line to get all the numbers the manufactuerer asks for, i.e. the Part Number and Serial Number you would read off the label on the drive?

Comment: OCZ has a utility that provides this information to you.

Comment: Command line in what OS?

Answer (score 1):

In Windows:

```
wmic diskdrive get /?
```

Will give you your choices:

```
Property                                Type                    Operation
========                                ====                    =========
Availability                            N/A                     N/A
BytesPerSector                          N/A                     N/A
Capabilities                            N/A                     N/A
CapabilityDescriptions                  N/A                     N/A
CompressionMethod                       N/A                     N/A
ConfigManagerErrorCode                  N/A                     N/A
ConfigManagerUserConfig                 N/A                     N/A
DefaultBlockSize                        N/A                     N/A
Description                             N/A                     N/A
DeviceID                                N/A                     N/A
ErrorCleared                            N/A                     N/A
ErrorDescription                        N/A                     N/A
ErrorMethodology                        N/A                     N/A
ErrorMethodology                        N/A                     N/A
Index                                   N/A                     N/A
InstallDate                             N/A                     N/A
InterfaceType                           N/A                     N/A
LastErrorCode                           N/A                     N/A
Manufacturer                            N/A                     N/A
MaxBlockSize                            N/A                     N/A
MaxMediaSize                            N/A                     N/A
MediaLoaded                             N/A                     N/A
MediaType                               N/A                     N/A
MinBlockSize                            N/A                     N/A
Model                                   N/A                     N/A
Name                                    N/A                     N/A
NeedsCleaning                           N/A                     N/A
NumberOfMediaSupported                  N/A                     N/A
PNPDeviceID                             N/A                     N/A
Partitions                              N/A                     N/A
PowerManagementCapabilities             N/A                     N/A
PowerManagementSupported                N/A                     N/A
SCSIBus                                 N/A                     N/A
SCSILogicalUnit                         N/A                     N/A
SCSIPort                                N/A                     N/A
SCSITargetId                            N/A                     N/A
SectorsPerTrack                         N/A                     N/A
SCSITargetId                            N/A                     N/A
SectorsPerTrack                         N/A                     N/A
Signature                               N/A                     N/A
Size                                    N/A                     N/A
Status                                  N/A                     N/A
StatusInfo                              N/A                     N/A
SystemName                              N/A                     N/A
TotalCylinders                          N/A                     N/A
TotalHeads                              N/A                     N/A
TotalSectors                            N/A                     N/A
TotalTracks                             N/A                     N/A
TracksPerCylinder                       N/A                     N/A
```

So, we can get the numbers with:

Model number:

```
wmic diskdrive get model
```

serial Number is not listed, but but exploring the namespaces through something like WMICreator, we see it should be:

```
wmic diskdrive get serialnumber
```

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, you can do this with various tools, including `lshw` which should be in your distribution's repositories. On Debian based systems, you can install with

```
sudo aptitude install lshw
```

You can then get the model and serial number with

```
$ sudo lshw | grep -A 10 disk | egrep 'product:|serial:|vendor'
```

Which, on my system, returns

```
            product: ST9500420AS
            vendor: Seagate
            serial: 5VJ6S0CJ
```